# Android : if else statement not working on Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have an activity with `CheckBox` & a `Button`. I used `SharedPreferences` to save the checkbox value.

The button saves the value of checkbox and opens another activity. The text of checkbox will explain it better.

```
check.setText("Show This Page On Start");
```

If checkbox is checked, this activity will be shown on start & if not, it will open another activity.

when i used this, the app force closes.

```
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", "false"))

    {  //launch another activity
    }
    else
    {
// do nothing
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What are you experiencing that makes you think if-else doesn't work?

Comment: why did u give false as string..?

Comment: can you post the error / logcat?

Comment: i edited my question, please take a look back.

Comment: Save boolean variable when your chekbox is checked.

Comment: @wqrahd it's because if the checkbox was not checked, it will launch another activity on restart.

Comment: Share your logcat output on the error. It probably will say that **"false"** cannot be parsed as **boolean**. Try sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", false) instead.

Comment: Try this ---- if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", false)).

Comment: i mean to say why you write "false".this is string. you should write false without "".

Comment: Yeah, i made a mistake here, it is actually `false` in my code not `"false"`.

Comment: if you find the solution please upvote the correct answers and accept one.

Comment: To access the relevant logcat output -if using eclipse- is menu - window - open view - find logcat in the list. When debugging your application, this view will list you what output does it generate, and what kind of exceptions have been thrown (in case you don't eat them in an empty catch block). You should copy-paste the error here in an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you...

**activity_main.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkShowThisPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show This Page On Start"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetCheckBoxValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private CheckBox  chkShowThisPage;
    private Button btnGetCheckBoxValue;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chkShowThisPage = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkShowThisPage);
        btnGetCheckBoxValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetCheckBoxValue);
         sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("showThisPage",true)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourAnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


        btnGetCheckBoxValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("showThisPage",chkShowThisPage.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourAnotherActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thnx Haresh for your help.

Comment: @RashedLone,Glad to help you,can you please upvote if is useful to you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", false))

    {  //launch another activity
    }
    else
    {
// do nothing
}
```

this is the correct way to access a boolean value

Answer (score 1):

you are passing string in getBoolean(see "false" in your code. its mean this is string you need to pass false without "").that is not the correct way to do.try this way

```
boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", false)

if (isChecked)
{ 
     //launch another activity
}
else
{
   // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a String as the default value for the SharedPreference to use if it's not set, which may cause your app to FC.

Try writing your condition passing a boolean as default:

```
 if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check_box_value", false)
     {...}
```

Comment: Yeah, i made a mistake here, it is actually `false` in my code not `"false"`.

Comment: Please share your logcat output about the error you get, so we can have more insight to your problem.

Comment: If the condition is correct, then the app tries to start one or the other activity. Do you have them both declared in your androidManifest.xml?